# Selecting volume chunk by rotation around axis

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, voxel

I have a 3D volume and I need to set some parts of it to zero.

The problem is that I don't know how to refer to the parts I want. I know the shape of the area I want to crop, but I need that area revolved around the Z axis.

*A picture's worth a thousand words*:

[image: Illustration of the problem]

The image shows the cross section of a 3D matrix in the XZ plane, in the middle is the Z axis. The area I want to select (or set to zero) in the volume is the red area, revolved around the green axis, the Z axis.

I'd rather have a solution that doesn't have a very big memory dependency (such as using `meshgrid` would) as these matrices can get quite big. Else, a `meshgrid` solution with cylindrical coordinates wouldn't be too difficult to make, as @Luis suggests.

How can I select this area?

Comment: Do you have the volume defined as a 3D grid? In that case, maybe convert to cylindrical coordinates, and then selecting the elements to zero out becomes a 2D problem

Comment: @LuisMendo the volume is a 3D matrix in matlabm its an image, no need of coordinates. I though of that, however I am worried of sizes, as the matrix can be very big, and making a `meshgrid` will increase the memory usage x4. Ill add that info to the qeustion